# Draw graph in GWT

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, gwt, jfreechart

We are using `JFreeChart` to draw graph in a GWT project, and now we looking for something more interactive to do this. Each one we can use to have a SVG format of graphs by the easiest way.

Trying to use `JFreeSVG`, but you must code also the behavior of mouseover to show popups.

Comment: I don't use `JFreeSVG`. Would an SVG image map be an alternative?